# Laravel migration failure apart from migration table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I've just attempted to move my first ever Laravel project over to a VPS I've installed all the required php extensions and set permissions as required however I'm trying to run a migration on my tables and I'm getting a connection refused but it first creates the migration table.

Obviously its connecting to the database fine to create the initial migration table not sure why it's throwing the error.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that you have installed the pdo extension?

Comment: PDO extension is fine. I ran PDO connection test to confirm.

Comment: Have you checked the DB directly to see if it trully creates the migration table?

Comment: Yeah the migration table is there but not populated.

Comment: If your `DB_HOST=localhost` try to use the IP instead `DB_HOST=127.0.0.1`. Also make sure that your MySQL port number is correct.

Comment: Port number is correct if i change to localhost I get a directory error and 127.0.0.1 is just showing connection refused.

Comment: check your DB config at config/database.php

Comment: Are you using a .env file or the default config?

Comment: I've tried both editing database.php to not use env and I've used env with the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out my server couldn't handle it and kept refusing connections.